# How to register multiple users in OWIN at a time?

Tags: sql, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

We are using Owin token based authentication for our application, I have to register all the users , I have a sql database table for username and password . Is there any way which I can write a method or function to register all the users at a time using the existing table ?
We are using angular js , entity framework , web-api2, sql 2008.

Comment: read all users from existing table and call "register" api for each one

Comment: It sounds promising !